# sqlite3 database System.BadImageFormatException in windows8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I have been trying for two days to get the SQL server 2012 to run with metro style when I finally discovered that metro style doesn't support this database client.
then I switched over to sqlite3 database.
I have created the classes for each database.But when i try to create the DB with this code

```
private async void CreateDatabase()
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("people");
        await conn.CreateTableAsync<users>();  
        await conn.CreateTableAsync<groups>();
    }
```

the following errors occur

> An exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in EduHaptics.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
in the line

```
SQLite3.SetDirectory(/*temp directory type*/2, Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path);
```

and same error at line

```
await conn.CreateTableAsync<users>();
```

tried to insert the path manually after i acquired it, but the same problems occur. I also navigated to that location it does exist but it is an empty folder.
I have a clue that it might be not reading the path well because of the String itself
but i don't know what to do!!
any help please
I am programming in visual studio 2013 64-bit environment and i acquired the sqlite-winrt81-3080401 version.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason It's only working if you set your project target platform to x64